# Running "node app.js" in loop breaks after first iteration

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm playing with making a script for the first time and would like to loop through and start a few node.js apps. Every time I start the first app though the loop breaks.

I've searched for some time to get a solution and looked into the `-n` flag used for `ssh`, `</dev/null` and using `(command)` to create a new terminal for commands. Perhaps the answer is in these but I'm not seeing it.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
for A in "${ARR[@]}"
do
    case $A in
        $APP1)
            DIR=$APP1_DIR; FILE=$APP1_FILE;
            ;;
        $APP2)
            DIR=$APP2_DIR; FILE=$APP2_FILE;
            ;;
        *)
            printf "KABLAMO!"
            ;;
    esac

    if [ -d $DIR ]; then
        ( cd $DIR && node $FILE );

        # get nothing after here on first iteration and script hangs at this point

    fi
done
```

Comment: What do the node.js scripts do? This will wait for the script to finish before continuing the loop. If you don't want to wait, run it in the background.

Comment: Oops, some typos when modifying for question, thanks for pointing out @Barmar The node.js scripts are servers that are always running and listening on ports, so they never finish really, this is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the scripts don't exit, you need to continue without waiting for them. So you should run them in the background with `&`:

```
(cd "$DIR" && node "$file" &)
```

Comment: You hero! Thanks a lot! A single ``&``, wish it was a lot more convoluted! :P Been Googling and staring at this for hours! Thanks so much for the lightning fast response!